# Не запускается бот на Heroku

Tags: python, telegram, heroku, бот

```
-----> Python app detected<br>
 !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using python-3.6.0, which is unsupported).<br>
 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.4).<br>
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes<br>
-----> Installing pip<br>
-----> Installing requirements with pip<br>
       Collecting telebot==0.0.3 (from -r <br>/tmp/build_f1efd238996ef145d7d99917fcd7ce27/Bot228-bot-<br>d2602ef/requirements.txt (line 1))<br>
         Downloading telebot-0.0.3.tar.gz<br>
       Collecting requests==2.7.0 (from telebot==0.0.3->-r <br>/tmp/build_f1efd238996ef145d7d99917fcd7ce27/Bot228-bot-<br>d2602ef/requirements.txt (line 1))<br>
         Downloading requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (470kB)<br>
       Installing collected packages: requests, telebot<br>
         Running setup.py install for telebot: started<br>
           Running setup.py install for telebot: finished with status <br>'done'
       Successfully installed requests-2.7.0 telebot-0.0.3<br>
-----> Discovering process types<br>
       Procfile declares types -> (none)<br>
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 56.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://botpls.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: _! The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using python-3.6.0, which is unsupported)._  Вам прямо говорят, что ваша версия python не поддерживается. Обновите Python и должен запуститься.

Comment: зачем вы думаете Procfile файл существует?

Comment: Вы бы приложили логи работы бота а не логи его деплоя

Comment: Предположу, что проблема в `Procfile declares types -> (none)`. К боту нужен файл Procfile (только это имя без расширения) - только имя. В его содержимом: `web: python Имя_бота.py`